# How would one change a container's content with a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to change the embed content inside a container from a tableviewcontroller to a map. I have tried searching it up, but all the questions have to do with tabview, which I am not doing. How would I start this process?

I also have tried with

```
- (IBAction)changer:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc1"];
    container.view = viewController1;
}
```

but that does not work

Comment: Do you want to fit the viewController to the container view?

Comment: Okay, I can spot at least 3 things wrong with this.

Comment: yeah, i want a uitableviewcontroller that us embedded in a container to switch to a viewController

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
MyViewController *viewController1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc1"];
viewController1.view.frame = self.container.bounds;

[viewController1 willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.container addSubview:viewController1.view];
[self addChildViewController:viewController1];
[viewController1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work: the container does not switch content. Thanks, though

Comment: @Alexyuiop Check if the viewController is properly instantiated, the storyboardID is correct and containerView is properly connected etc

Comment: @Anupdas what does it mean to properly connect a containerView? if you create it in IB, do you have to do something more than just dragging it into its VC?

Comment: @mkc842 OP was not using ContainerView available in storyboard, but just a regular view to which he was adding viewController as child. I was referring to if IBOutlet to that view was connected :)

Comment: @Anupdas cool thanks, i've got my thing working now thanks to your code. but i'd still like to understand what is the purpose of notifying the child VC it will move to the parent and then telling it that it did indeed do so?

Comment: also it should be noted that if you have any views above the container, it seems you will need to use `viewController1.view.frame = self.container.FRAME;` rather than bounds, or else the view you added will appear at the top of the VC (covering up other stuff) regardless of the container's position. at least, that was the case for me.

Comment: @mkc842 The usual practice is to add a viewController as subView to the container not on top of it. If you want to just cover the containerView the above code would work fine. By declaring the will move and didMove methods is to notify the usual events triggered in a vc when they are being presented in the view.

Comment: Doesn't kill the previous VC once it switches... (?)

Answer (score 0):

this is my implementation in Swift:

```
func navigateTo(vc: NSViewController){
    vc.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds;
    if let currentSubview = containerView.subviews.first {
        self.containerView.replaceSubview(currentSubview, with: vc.view)
    } else {
        self.containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
    }
    self.addChildViewController( vc )
}
```

For an animated transition, i implement awakeFromNib

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    let animation: CATransition = CATransition()
    animation.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    animation.duration = 0.75
    animation.delegate = self
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    if let _ = containerView {
        containerView.wantsLayer = true
        containerView.animations = NSDictionary(object: animation, forKey: "subviews") as! [String : AnyObject]
    }
}
```

and replace the line *self.containerView.replaceSubview* with:

```
self.containerView.animator().replaceSubview(currentSubview, with: vc.view)
```